# derivative of expected value with respect to parameter in both pdf and expectation

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-derivative, expectation

Say $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ with pdf $f(x, \mu)$. We are interested in expectation of $g(x)$. Then
$$E[g(x, \mu)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x, \mu) f(x, \mu) dx$$

Now I want partial derivative of this. Why does the following hold?
$$\frac{d}{d\mu}E[g(x, \mu)]= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dg(x, \mu)}{d\mu} f(x, \mu) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x, \mu) \frac{df(x)}{d\mu} dx$$

I mean, why not the chain rule inside the integral and only one function is partially differentiated?

It is easy to understand the rationale of it, but I am struggling with the proof...

Comment: $g(X)$ is not a random variable; $g(X)$ is. $x$ on the right is not the same as the $x$ on the left. $E(g(x))$ is just $g(x)$, plain and simple, and its derivative wrt $x$ is what you would get in Calculus 101.

Comment: So x is not really x. g(x) is rather g(x_0), while f(x) is f(x_T), where T - terminal value?

Comment: Dang typo! It should have said $g(x)$ is not a random variable. I have no idea what $x_0$ and $x_T$ are; please explain.

Comment: I am thinking here in terms of stochastic processes, but it is the same as random variable. Say we define a random step that follows a normal distribution - x. We are interested in expected value - this will be E[X_0], where X_0 is the current state. Now we want to take derivative of it: $\partial_{X_0} E[X_0]$

Comment: Sorry, see my edit in original post...

Comment: Ok, but if you did not know that the integral is expected value. How would you prove that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}\int g(x,\mu) f(x,\mu)dx = \int\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} g(x,\mu) f(x,\mu)dx$$ Also, see slide 9 here. Likelihood ration method for calculating partial derivatives of expectation. It seems that second integral always hold. As I said I understand logic of it, the way you describe it in equation, but can not come up with a mathematically robust proof. http://www.hpcfinance.eu/sites/www.hpcfinance.eu/files/20140214_1130_Mark_Cathcart.pdf

Answer (score 10):

This question has such messy notation and mixes up so many different things that it is difficult to
figure out what exactly is being asked.

Let $g(x,\mu)$ denote an ordinary two-variable real-valued function of
two real variables. We will assume that the function is integrable with
respect to both variables. Let $X$ denote a normal random variable
with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Thus, $X$ has a probability
density function given by
$$f_X(t) = f(t,\mu) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}
\left(\frac{t-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right),
~~-\infty < t < \infty.\tag{1}$$
Now, there is *nothing* random about the function $g(x,\mu)$ and so its
*expected value* is just $g(x,\mu)$ 1tself. Indeed the same notion,

> the **expected** value of a constant is the constant itself

is a fundamental notion of probability theory (as well as of
real life).
More formally,
$$E[g(x,\mu)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x,\mu)f_X(t)\,\mathrm dt
= g(x,\mu)\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t,\mu)\,\mathrm dt
= g(x,\mu). \tag{2}$$
and it is worth noting in passing that we would have obtained the
same answer even if we had used a different density function for
$X$, or indeed a discrete mass function, etc.  From $(2)$, we have
that 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}E[g(x,\mu)]
= \frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}g(x,\mu)\tag{3}$$
and that's all there is to it. You could, if you like,
write $(3)$ as 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}E[g(x,\mu)]
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}g(x,\mu)
f(t,\mu)\,\mathrm dt\tag{4}$$
which *sort of* looks like what you want to prove, but actually
isn't at all the same.

---

"But, but, but,..." you splutter indignantly, "All this is pure hooey.
*Everybody,* with the possible exception of Old Harry And His Old Aunt, knows that $(1)$ is incorrect: the density of $X$ is $f_X(x)$ and
not $f_X(t)$ as you have written in $(1$). Thus $(2)$ is not at all what
I *know* $E[g(x,\mu)]$ to be. It's got to be
$$E[g(x,\mu)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x,\mu)f(x,\mu)\,\mathrm dx
\tag{5}$$
the way I wrote it in my question."

All right, have it your way.. If $Y = g(X,\mu)$ is a *random* 
variable that is
a *function* of the random variable $X$, then the 
*[law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)* gives us that
$$E[g(X,\mu)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x,\mu)f(x,\mu)\,\mathrm dx.
\tag{6}$$
If you cannot see any difference between $(5)$ and $(6)$,
compare the 5th character in each equation; that is a fundamental
difference.

The equation $(6)$ can be differentiated on both sides
with respect to $\mu$ giving
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}E[g(X,\mu)] &= \frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x,\mu)f(x,\mu)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(f(x,\mu)\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}g(x,\mu)+g(x,\mu)\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}f(x,\mu)\right)\,\mathrm dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,\mu)\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}g(x,\mu)\,\mathrm dx
+ \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x,\mu)\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}f(x,\mu)\,\mathrm dx\tag{7}
\end{align}
which more nearly resembles what you want to prove if you replace
that second $=$ sign in your question with a $+$ sign.
But note that 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}f(x,\mu)
= \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2}f(x,\mu)$$
and so *if $g(x,\mu)$ is an even function of $(x-\mu)$,* then
the integrand in the second integral in $(7)$ is a odd function
of $(x-\mu)$, the value of that integral is $0$ and so
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}E[g(X,\mu)]
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,\mu)\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}g(x,\mu)\,\mathrm dx$$
just the way you want it.

Comment: +1. This is a worthy try to address one recurring misconception in the field, whose damages can be seen in countless questions on the site. Let us hope this has some nonzero effect...